# How to show a set is compact in a function space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I have a question asking if $\{f_n\}$ is a compact in $C_b([0,\infty))$ (bounded continuous) with $||\cdot||_{L^\infty}$.
The sequence is 
$$f_n (t) = \sin\sqrt{t+(2n\pi)^2},$$

I have showed that

- $f_n \rightarrow 0$ pointwise.
- The convergence is uniform when looking at $t$ in a bounded interval,
  and it is not uniform when $t\in[0,\infty)$.
- $\{f_n\}$ is equi-continuous.

Questions:

1. Now assume that the space is $C_b([0,N])$, can I use Arzelà–Ascoli theorem to show $\{f_n\}$ is sequential compact? Which implies compactness since $C_b([0,N])$ is a metric space?
2. How would I approach this kind of problem, which definition of compactness should I use when working on function spaces? Complete and totally bounded; every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For the first one, sure, though you don't need to, because you've already proven there's a uniformly convergent subsequence: it's just the sequence itself. For the second one, it really depends on the context; it is useful to know a variety of characterizations of compactness of metric spaces. The same is true on the real line; consider, for example, the result that a continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous. You probably proved that using the open cover definition of compactness. Yet much of the time it is convenient to work with sequences instead.

Comment: Thanks, and good point on 1. I was thinking too much about how to apply Arzela-Ascoli theorem to this, and I forgot that I showed compactness on $C_b[0,N]$ from previous result. :)

Comment: All the versions of the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem that I know assume that the domain of definition of the functions is compact, whereas $[0, \infty)$ is not. Are you using some other version of the theorem?

Comment: @AlexM. I did not apply Arzela-Ascoli directly, as you said it doesn't work with $[0,\infty)$. And that is why I am asking if there is any other ways of solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You proved that $\sup_{x\in [0,N]}|f_n(x)|\to 0$, hence $f_n\to 0$ in the space $C[0,1]$. If $(x_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a convergent sequence in a metric space, then the set $\{x_n,n\geqslant 1\}$ has a compact closure.
2. Since the potential limit point can only be the null function and it does not belong to $\{f_n,n\geqslant 1\}=:S$, the set $S$ cannot be compact. But it may have a priori a compact closure. We can investigate whether a converging subsequence exists. Since such a sequence should converge uniformly to $0$, and no subsequence is uniformly convergent (take a suitable $t$), we conclude that the closure of $S$ is not compact.